# What does "what you're in for" means

Tags: meaning

What does *what you're in for* mean in following sentence?

> The journey seems intense and, frankly, it often is. It's important that you understand *what you're in for*, particularly if you go it alone.

Comment: Be in for sth:
    
- to be going to experience something unpleasant very soon:
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/be-in-for-sth

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Andrei. http://english.stackexchange.com/help/asking Good Luck.

Comment: Not necessarily unpleasant. You may be *in for a good time*.

Comment: I think the meaning referred to by @Josh61 usually takes the form "You are going to be in for *it*" (or sometimes just "... going to be for *it*"), with the "it" signifying the dreaded consequence... Asking what one is "in for" is as Zbyněk Dráb's answer

Comment: This question has four close votes, but it seems like it might have been a good candidate for migration to [ell.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It roughly translates to "What you're getting into", "What you can expect".

Comment: Interestingly, *what you're in for* invariably alludes to ***bad*** future possibilities, whereas *what's in it for you* almost always refers to future ***benefits***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Didn't you ever have the sense that you were *in for a good time*.

Answer (score 0):

A typical situation for the idiomatic expression "to be in for sth" would be:

Mother shouting after her young son who has hurt his little sister and is running away: Boy, you are in for a sound beating when you come home.

My explanation for this "in for" is: You are in my bad  books for a sound beating.

The expression can be used for negative things one has to expect as in

- He's in for a shock.
- I'm afraid we're in for a storm.